# Unpacking three values packed into a Long

Tags: java, kotlin, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have the following bitwise operation that generates a hash:

```
(z shl 28) or (y shl 14) or x // (z << 28 | y << 14 | x) in java
```

I want to be able to deduce x, y and z from the hash calculated above. I can get Z and X every time, but I'm having trouble getting Y - it only works occasionally.

Z will always be less than 4. And x and y will be no bigger than the max short value.

This is what I'm doing:

```
    val hash = 684297131L // sample hash
    val z = hash shr 28
    val y = hash shr 14 // this works only sometimes
    val x = hash and 0xfff
```

I think I'm missing something simple here, any help appreciated.

Comment: From a single value with 2^n bits, why do you expect to be able to deduce _three_ values with 2^n bits?  Or are x, y, z smaller than the hash domain?

Comment: Z will always be less than 4. And x and y will be no bigger than the max short value.

Comment: And what's the domain of the hash?  You have it as a long here, but you need at least 34 bits to recover two shorts and a value < 4.

Comment: Yea the domain will always be a Long. A long is 64 bits right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "hash" doesn't look too much like a hash.  It looks more like packing 3 fields into a long.

You can get `x`, `y`, and `z` that produce the same "hash" like this:

```
val z = hash shr 28
val y = (hash shr 14) and 0x3fff
val x = hash and 0x3fff
```

This may be exactly what you want. There are different numbers that could produce the same hash, but these are the simplest.